# How to reposition code previously placed in Appdelegate.m

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I think the title of the question may be misleading as I'm not quite sure how to word this in a line.
I'm trying to implement a reveal controller (like those seen in the Facebook app), and I'm using a sweet pre-made solution **SWRevealViewController** which can be [found here](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). 
In one of the most simple examples the author provides (Example/project 2), in the Appdelegate.m file the reveal controller stuff is established:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window = window;
    FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
    RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
    UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
    initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    mainRevealController.delegate = self;

    self.viewController = mainRevealController;

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Where `viewcontroller` is defined in the appdelegate.h file by

> @property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *viewController;

So this displays the reveal controller as the root view controller. For my app, my root view controller is different and I only start using the reveal controller later in the app. My root view controller is the login screen, and then the proceeding view is where I want to implement this.

I guess my questions are:

- Firstly, is it correct to put the login screen as the root view controller? Should I be using some sort of modal view to pop this up then get rid of it?
- How and where would I go about putting the stuff previously found in the delegate files? Or do they remain there but are not assigned to the root view controller?

I feel really in the dark about this, so forgive me if it seems completely trivial. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have thought about this problem recently. In fact all other third party implementations I found all have this setup.

My recommendation is to change the root controller to the reveal controller and build everything up from there. You can disable reveal for your original root, login or any other controller. I did it once and it was not as painful as anticipated.

Comment: Only just seen this - thanks for the advice. Eventually I just implemented it from the root controller and disabled any option to show it on the root controller. Works throughout the app from there just fine

Comment: Cool. Although you got there yourself as well, you should accept above answer.

Comment: Im not really sure its what Im looking for though. Id still like more of a clear explanation as to, given my current structure, where I could have replaced stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the party, the behavior you want is easy to implement, just think about it as a normal navigation stack. Let's take the example 2 which you were following along the way (you don't need to move the code out of the delegate). Instead of setting the front view controller as the root of the front navigation controller, you should set the login view controller as the root of the front navigation controller.

Here is the example before:

```
FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
        initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
```

And here is the example after setting the login view controller:

```
LoginViewController *loginVC =[[LoginViewController alloc]init];//instead of frontViewController
RearViewController *rearViewController = [[RearViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginVC];//instead of frontViewController
UINavigationController *rearNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rearViewController];

SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
    initWithRearViewController:rearNavigationController frontViewController:frontNavigationController];
```

Don't forget to create the `LoginViewController` or whatever you choose to name with its nib file and to import it.
In `LoginViewController`, you need to implement the action code to move to the `frontviewcontroller`:

```
FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:frontViewController animated:YES];
```

Et voila.